# Get Web App to auto refresh database not using update model wizard

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

How do I get my database to auto refresh as raw data is coming into and updating a MySql database. I'm not just simply talking about updating the models as I will need to do that but also the views automatically every 5 minutes or so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a fairly vague question, perhaps it would be better to give an example of the data on your page then we might be able to suggest something that suits it best.  But if i've understood correctly there's a few ways to go about it, you can use this as a starting point.

1. Would be to use a javascript MVVM library (knockout) and make ajax calls to fetch new data and then push those changes to the view model.  This would require a fair bit of reading on your behalf though (more than I would be willing to put in an answer here - worth the effort though).
2. you could use something like signalr to push notifications / updates to the browser (you could combine this with option one as well) and javascript/jquery to update the page.
3. you could use ajax on a timer, to fetch data and use javascript/jquery to update the page.
4. if you wanted a simpler approach you could use a javascript timer to refresh the page after 5 minutes.  Then your controller will fetch the latest data etc, might be a bit annoying if people are in the middle of something though.

Edit:

Since your not interacting with your data it may be easiest to just fetch your data on page load and set a timer to fetch it again every 5 minutes

```
public class MyStatsModel
{
     public int StatA { get; set; }
     public string StatB { get; set; }
     public double StatC { get; set; }
     // etc
}

[HttpGet]
public JsonResult FetchLatestStats()
{
     var dbStats = // get latest stats
     var myStatsModel = new MyStatsModel() { StatA = dbStats.A }; // etc
     return new Json(MyStatsModel);
}

 $(document).ready(function () {
     var interval = 5 * 60 * 1000;  // 5 minutes
     var getLatestStats = function() {
         $.ajax({
             type: 'GET',
             url: '/Stats/FetchLatestStats'
             dataType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             success: function(myStatsModel) {
                 $('#someElementA').text(myStatsModel.StatA);
                 $('#someElementB').text(myStatsModel.StatB);
                 // etc
             },
             error: function() {
                 alert('There was an error fetching latest stats!');
             }
         });
     };        
     setInterval(getLatestStats(), interval);
 };
```

Comment: My data is a machine producing cloth and the machine has software built into it to keep up with needle breaks, total yard of cloth produced, current knitter, etc. Data that will be changing all the time. All this data is stored in many tables into a giant MySql database.

Comment: Added a quick example

Comment: Okay that's very helpful, if I am using MVC can I use the above as a prototype for a update controller or should I just make a completely separate class in my project too update certain views?

Comment: If your controller was called StatsController (as the ajax url was /stats/fetchlateststats) you could use that as a general template. Obviously just tailor your model to your actual data.